# Rustup nightly toolchain does not allow to use unstable features of Rust Lang

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup, rust-no-std

I am new to Rust and I've run into a problem with rustup for the first time.
The point is that it doesn't allow me to use unstable feature of the language although I explicitly run it with `nightly` modifier `rustup run nightly cargo build -Z build-std=core --target <Target>`

I have already tried
`rustup override set nightly`
and
`rustup default nightly`

It changes config in ~/.rustup/settings.toml but does nothing when i am trying to use [unstable] or -Z I will still get this error:
`error: the` -Z`flag is only accepted on the nightly channel of Cargo, but this is the`stable `channel`

Or different errors (in case of [unstable] in .cargo/config) which signal that stable channel is used instead of nightly

Comment: What `cargo` command generates this error?

Comment: Try `cargo +nightly ...` instead of `rustup run nightly cargo ...`

Comment: What is the output of `cargo --version` after you have set `nightly` as the default channel?

Comment: 1) I am trying to do `cargo build -Z build-std=core --target <Target>`
2) After `rustup default nightly` i am still getting stable version with `rustc --version` and `cargo --version`. It seems like a problem with my $PATH variable since i have stable toolchain in my PATH and it is not overwritten with rustup commands

Comment: Please post the output of `which cargo` (or `where cargo` on windows). You might have multiple versions of cargo installed. It should say something like `<home>/.cargo/bin/cargo` or similar. If not, then that's your problem. Also, if people say 'what is the output', they mean 'please show us the exact output', not 'please describe the output with your own words', just fyi.

Comment: `cargo +nightly build -Z build-std=core --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` works for me, after having installed the `rust-src` component.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve? *"I'm new to Rust"* and *"-Z build-std=core"* sound to me like a very weird combination, indicating an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). The `build-std` flag is only useful in a very specific set of usecases, and is usually not something relevant for beginners.

Comment: Well, I am just trying to follow along an interesting tutorial on how to build a little OS with Rust) I need next expression in my config file to follow along:
`
[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]
`

But stable version ignores those lines due to unstable flag

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to everyone, who tried to help me with this issue.
I had a $PATH overwritten in my .bashrc to expose rust stable version for VSCode to use it in rust-analyzer plugin, so every call to cargo or rustc proxied to stable version, that were exposed in $PATH, after removing it rustup works as expected. But I still have to manage the way to make my VSCode rust-analyzer plugin work again without Rust explicitly exposed in $PATH variable)